# Add ValueTransformer in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, binding

I'd like to add a ValueTransformer to a cocoa binding.
I've created a ValueTransformer class but it is not visible in IB.
When added as ValueTransformer in IB the app will crash at start

```
class myTransformer: ValueTransformer {

override func valueClassForBinding(_ binding: String) -> AnyClass? {
    return NSString.self
}

override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    return "test"
}


}
```

> Cannot find value transformer with name myTransformer

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, register your value converter name to NSValueTransformerName.

```
extension
NSValueTransformerName {
    static let myTransformerName = NSValueTransformerName( rawValue: "myTransformer")
}
```

Then register your value converter in the very beginning of your program, i.e. AppDelegate's initializer.

```
@NSApplicationMain class
AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    override
    init() {
        super.init()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer( myTransformer(), forName: .myTransformerName )
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/valuetransformer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value transformer class to the controller class in the initialize code.
Then you will find your value transformer in interface builder in the right place. It will show in Interface Builder right after like so:

You need to write the value transformer in a proper way. [Check this out](http://nshipster.com/nsvaluetransformer/).

[image]

[Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/Registration.html)

> Value transformers are typically registered by an application’s delegate class, in response to receiving a initialize: class message. This allows registration to occur early in the application startup process, providing access to the value transformers as nib files load.

Hope it helps.