# Binding ImageView to Asset Catalogue

Tags: swift, macos, binding, nsvaluetransformer

I have a NSTableView bound to myArrayController, controlling an object that looks a bit like this

```
class myObject: NSObject {
    @objc  var name: String
    @objc  var image: String
}
```

In my tableview, I have a column with an NSImageView, that I want to bind to the 'image' value of the associated object.

In my Assets.xcassets library, I have imagesets.

Now this is where my knowledge stops.

For the binding, I have 3 options

- value
- valuepath
- valueUrl

just passing a string corresponding to the name of an image set to either of these options doesn't work.

So, I guess I need to use a Value Transformer, but I haven't got a clue on how to set that up.

Your help is very much appreciated

BTW, this is all MacOS/Swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add ValueTransformer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632442/add-valuetransformer-in-swift)

Comment: Another solution is to add a calculated image property in an extension.

Comment: @Willeke: would you have a some code example of either approach? I studied it, but can't get my head around it

Comment: Value transformer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/valuetransformer

Comment: Read-Only Computed Properties: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html